# Track the number of visits to each SharePoint page in the communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing

could we track the number of visits to each page, where/how people navigate, and who is accessing the site based on SharePoint group permission(e.g. Finance teams vs. other HQ staff vs. field staff).  Could you please advise on this?

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question. In classic SP we would need to inject some code in the page that would log the required info to Application Insight or similar repository. In Modern Sharepoint that is not an option so SPFx seems to be the answer.
Perhaps you can find inspiration here : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Communication-site-with-Google-Analytics/td-p/252473